# Batch script to read a specific line from a log file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to write a batch script that reads 18th line from a .log file and outputs the same. The .log file name varies each time. abc_XXXX.log where xxxx are process IDs. Below is the code I am trying to run to achieve this.

```
:Test1
set "xprvar=" for /F "skip=17 delims=" %%p in (abc*.log) do (echo %%p& goto 
break)

:break
pause
goto END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is also an option using `FindStr`

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Tokens=1-2* Delims=:" %%A In ('FindStr/N "^" "abc_*.log" 2^>Nul'
) Do If %%B Equ 18 Echo %%A:%%C
Pause
```

The above example `Echo`es the `<filename>`:`<18th line content>`, but there's no reason in the appropriate situation why you couldn't change that to read:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Tokens=1-2* Delims=:" %%A In ('FindStr/N "^" "abc_*.log" 2^>Nul'
) Do If %%B Equ 18 Set "xprvar=%%C"
```

*If there is more than one matching filename in the directory, the variable would be set to the content in the last file parsed.*

Answer (score 1):

`set var=anyCommand` doesn't work. It just sets the var to the literal string.

The usage of a`for /f` is the right way, just the variable assignment works different:

```
for /F "skip=17 delims=" %%p in ('dir /b abc*.log') do  ( set "xprvar=%%p"& goto break )
```

Comment: I tried `for /F "skip=17 delims=" %p in (abc*.log) do  ( set "xprvar=%p"& goto break )` When i run it i get an error saying "The system cannot find the file abc*.log" even though the file is residing in the same folder where the batch is being run.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
FOR %%f IN (abc*.log) DO (
 SET "reported="
 FOR /f "skip=17delims=" %%p IN (%%f) DO IF NOT DEFINED reported (
  ECHO %%p
  SET "reported=Y"
 )
)
```

Assign each filename in turn to `%%f`.

For each filename found, clear the `reported` flag then read the file, skipping the first 17 lines. `echo` the 18th line and set the `reported` flag so that the remainder of the lines are not `echo`ed.